# Cucumber Spring Framework to automate Google Calculator query

Tags: spring, selenium, automation, cucumber, test-framework

I am creating a Spring Framework to automate the Google Calculator
I have a feature file that has some values as defined below

```
Feature: Google Calculator
  Calculator should calculate correct calculations

  Scenario Outline: Add numbers
    Given I am on google calculator page
    When I add number "<number1>" to number "<number2>"
    Then I should get an answer of "<answer>"

Examples:
  | number1 | number2 | answer |
  | 1       | 2       | 3      |
  | 4       | 5       | 9      |
```

I am trying to use the Given, When , Then to create a test that any number from this feature file could be used in the Calculator
My Steps are as follows:

```
@Scope("test")
@ContextConfiguration("classpath:spring-context/test-context.xml")
public class GivenSteps {
@Autowired
private WebDriver webDriver;


@Given("^I am on google calculator page$")
public void iAmOnGoogleCalculatorPage() throws Throwable {
    webDriver.get("https://www.google.ie/search?q=calculator");
}

@When("^I add number \"([^\"]*)\" to number \"([^\"]*)\"$")
public void i_add_number_to_number(Integer number1, Integer number2) throws Throwable {
    WebElement googleTextBox = webDriver.findElement(By.id("cwtltblr"));


    googleTextBox.sendKeys(Keys.ENTER);

    throw new PendingException();


}
@Then("^I should get the correct answer again$")
public void thecorrectanswertest2() throws Throwable{

    WebElement calculatorTextBox = webDriver.findElement(By.id("cwtltblr"));
    String result = calculatorTextBox.getText();
}}
```

My question is how do I code the piece where an number can be choosen and an answer verified from the table in the feature ?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use the @Then like as below to compare the answer from table?-

```
@Then("^I should get the correct answer \"([^\"]*)\" again$")
public void thecorrectanswertest2(String answer) throws Throwable{

WebElement calculatorTextBox = webDriver.findElement(By.id("cwtltblr"));
String result = calculatorTextBox.getText();

if(answer.equalsIgnoreCase(result))
  System.out.println("Test Passed");

}
```

Try this once. It should work

Comment: However I am wondering how the @When will work, how do i insert the variable numbers in this test ?

Comment: or declare number1 and number2 as string or convert them to string.then use googleTextBox.sendKeys(number1) and googleTextBox.sendKeys(number2);